# Angle bisector in triangle, quick question: $|AE| = \frac{bc}{a+c}$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Triangle $ABC$; $AB=c, BC=a, AC=b$; angle bisector of angle $(c, a)$ cuts $AC$ in point $E$.
Why is the following true?
$$|AE| = \frac{bc}{a+c}$$
Where does that come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: We get $$\frac{AE}{EC}=\frac{c}{a}$$
And $$EC=b-AE$$ then we get $$\frac{b-AE}{AE}=\frac{c}{a}$$

Comment: you mean $\frac ca$ ? But I still can't get to what I asked from here.

Comment: It is the angle bisector theorem

Comment: Yes, I know it. I tried to get to what I asked with the angle bisector theorem, but I couldn't. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry for that typo!

Answer (score 2):

let $\beta$ be half of the bisected angle, and $\theta$ denote the angle AEB.

then the sine rule in triangle AEB gives:

$$
\frac{|AE|}{\sin \beta} = \frac{c}{\sin \theta}
$$

and the sine rule in triangle CEB gives:

$$
\frac{|EC|}{\sin \beta} = \frac{a}{\sin (\pi - \theta)}
$$

since $\sin \theta = \sin (\pi-\theta)$ and $|AE|+|EC| = b$, the result follows

Answer (score 1):

The angle bisector theorem:
$$\frac{CE}{AE}=\frac ac$$
Then:
$$\frac{bc}{a+c}=\frac{b}{\frac ac+1}=\frac{b}{\frac{CE}{AE}+1}=\frac{AE\cdot b}{CE+AE}=AE$$